# Why the result is getId:f() instead of 123?

Tags: javascript

Isn't the function get executed when it is called?

```
let app=(function(){
      let carId=123;
      let getId=function(){
        return carId;
      };
      getId();
      return{
        getId:getId
      };
    })();

    console.log(app);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an object in which you create `getId` attribute which is reference to `getId` variable which is a function, you simply made a `closure`, you can now call `app.getId()`

Answer (score 1):

The function does execute when it's called, but you're not doing anything with the result it returns. Instead, you're returning an object with a reference to the function, not the result. Try this instead:

```
let app=(function(){
  let carId=123;
  let getId=function(){
    return carId;
  };
  return{
    getId:getId()
  };
})();

console.log(app);
```

Or, even better, call it only when needed later, not in the middle of your closure:

```
let app=(function(){
  let carId=123;
  let getId=function(){
    return carId;
  };
  return{
    getId:getId
  };
})();

console.log(app.getId());
```